# Table view single tap not working after reloading

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a array of data and populated in table view.then i added the values to the array dynamically and reload the table by using code

```
[self.listTableView reloadData];
```

after reloading, very first time the single tap is not working.

thanks in advance (sorry for my english).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're reloading the table on the main thread.  It's possible that you're trying to reload the table on a background thread from the async task used to download the information for the table view data source.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.listTableView reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the TableView properties "single selection" or "multiple selection" in the StoryBoard/Xib or even programmatically are turned on appropriately.
2. Did you implement the function didDeselectRowAtIndexPath rather than didSelectRowAtIndexPath?
3. I heard the attribute "Show Selection On Touch" in the Storyboard/xib can cause problems, try toggling it and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: 1.single selection only 2. didSelectRowAtIndexPath only used 3. tried is not working